# Softlayer - Is Windows Virtual Server additional disk already formatted?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I provisioned a Windows Virtual Server (`WIN_2012-STD_64`) by following command

```
slcli vs create -d dal09 -H dal09ak001 -D xx.yy.com -c 1 -m 1024 -o WIN_2012-STD_64 -n 10 --vlan-public 957429 --vlan-private 957431 --disk 100 --disk 25 --disk 25 --disk 25 --san
```

When the server was provisioned, I logged in to the server and checked in the disk management utility that the additional disks attached to the server are already formatted. Please see the image below

[image]

Also I am able to create a folder in the additional disk (`Volume G`)

Does that mean softlayer formats the additional disks while provisioning a windows virtual server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yep, when you order wiht additional disks the disks are already formated, but when you modify your VM and add more disks they are not formated.

Regards